# Playframework: How to add custom repositories path such that it does not download on the root path

Tags: scala, playframework

Where to specify this line? -Divy.home=/custom/location to play.

Comment: Can You explain a bit more?

Comment: Am running the dr-elephant application for hadoop jobs monitoring. It uses Playframework where the dependencies for the framework are downloaded to the path /home/user which is a root path where i have less resources. I want an alternative to download the dependencies to custom path.

Comment: some this line must be defined in playframework.                                    <!-- configure caches -->
      <caches repositoryCacheDir="${user.home}/.ivy2/cache">. I want to override the settings here. Most forums suggest of finding the settings in ivy2settings.xml but am unable to find it. Also, some suggestions say that i can pass play -Divy.Home/custom/location to get this done. No clue.